# SED replace expression "within" a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, date, awk, sed

I have to change a CSV file column (the date) which is written in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

and I would like it to be

```
YYYY.MM.DD
```

I can write a succession of 2 *sed* rules *piped* one to the other like :

```
sed 's/-/./' file.csv | sed 's/-/./'
```

but this is not clean. my question is: is there a way of assigning variables in sed and tell it that `YYYY-MM-DD`  should be parsed as `year=YYYY ; month=MM ; day=DD` and then tell it

```
write $year.$month.$day
```

or something similar? Maybe with awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use groups and access the year, month, and day directly via backreferences:

```
sed 's#\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)#\1.\2.\3#g'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is equivalent to supplying the "global" replacement flag:

```
sed 's/-/./g' file.csv
```

`sed` has no variables, but it does have numbered groups:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/\1.\2.\3/g' file.csv
```

or, if your `sed` has no `-r`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1.\2.\3/g' file.csv
```

Comment: no, in this way I will replace also "-" in other fields and this is not wat I want...

Comment: @Danduk82 But then your two piped commands will not work either. Anyway, I added a way using groups.

Comment: ok. This is very interesting. I didn't know the *-r* option. +1 too

Comment: @Danduk82 `-r` is a GNU extension. More portable option would be `-E`.

Comment: @jaypal and I didn't know POSIX sed had `-E`, thanks :)

Comment: The original scripts would work fine if you know the first two dashes should always be substituted. The same can trivially be done in a single script with two commands; `s/-/./;s/-/./`

Comment: @LevLevitsky You're welcome. I am not sure if it is available on solaris (might be on `xpg4`) but BSD and GNU `sed` both have it which makes it a little more portable than `-r`. `:)`

Comment: _POSIX_ sed does NOT have `-E` (see http://man.cx/sed; i.e.: NO support for _extended_ regexes), but, as @jaypal states, both GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` (including OSX) support `-E` for use with _extended_ regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `sed` command also,

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\-\([0-9]\{2\}\)\-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1.\2.\3/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ (echo '2056-05-15'; echo '2086-12-15'; echo 'foo-bar-go') | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1.\2.\3/g'
2056.05.15
2086.12.15
foo-bar-go
```

Comment: `\-` is same as `-` since it is not special.

Comment: Yep, but the @Lev's solution won't work for me. So that i posted this.

Comment: `:)` It's because his solution missed including a `-` between numbers. If you remove \ before `-` in your solution, you'll notice that it would work just fine.

Comment: i edited for you.But may or maynot a backslash before `-` wouldn't a matter at all.

Comment: Yes, escaping a non-special character won't hurt, but is probably mis-leading. Thanks for the edit though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution with `awk`:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { gsub("-", ".", $1); print }' file.csv
```

- `BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }` tells `awk` to break the input lines into fields by `,` (variable `FS`, the [input] Field Separator), as well as to also use `,` when *outputting* *modified* input lines (variable `OFS`, the Output Field Separator).
- `gsub("-", ".", $1)` replaces all `-` instances with `.` in field *1*

  - The assumption is that the data is in the *1st* field, `$1`; if the field index is a different one, replace the `1` in `$1` accordingly.
- `print` simply outputs the modified input line, terminated with a newline.